# How to show $D_X(fY)=X(f)Y+fD_xY$

Tags: differential-geometry

How to show $$D_X(fY)=X(f)Y+fD_XY$$
where $X$ is vector field on $E^n$ , $Y$ is $C^{\infty}$ vector field on $E^n$ and $f$ element of $C(E^n,R)$

Comment: That is basically one of the defining characteristics of a [derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)), and one does not _prove_ definitions. I'm afraid you will need to give more details on what exactly your question is.

Comment: Well Im trying to understand covariant derivative and directional derivative as part of this I need to show this equation is correct

Comment: Sorry I changed it to _show_

Comment: Again, *write your definition of covariant derivative*, because "a $\Bbb R$-bilinear map of vector fields which satisfies that condition" is one of the possible **definitions** of "covariant derivative".

Comment: Derivative along vector field $[X(f)]\mid _p=X_p[f], X \in \chi(E^n), f \in C(E^n,R), p\in E^n$ covariant derivative along curve $\alpha'(t)[f]={d(f\circ\alpha)\over dt}=D_{\alpha'(t)}f$

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just a verification of definition.
\begin{align}
D_X (fY) & = \langle X,D(fY) \rangle \\ & = \langle X, \textrm{d}f \otimes Y+fDY \rangle \\ & = \langle X,\textrm{d}f \otimes Y \rangle + \langle X,fDY \rangle \\ & = X(f)Y + fD_XY
\end{align}
Hence the result.